# Evaluate this question based on series and limits.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

> For $a \in \mathbb R,a≠-1$
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^a+2^a+\cdots +n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[(na+1)+(na+2)+(na+3)+\cdots+(na+n)]}=\frac{1}{60}$$
>   Then find the values of $a $.

I tried to solve this problem using approximation but I got the the value of $a$ as $\dfrac{-3}{2}$. The source of this question is JEE advanced $2013$ of India.

Comment: Yadati Khan thanks for the edit. I was not able to write properly in proper format.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that $a=-3/2$ is wrong?

Comment: Yes I know that fact that is why I am asking this question here.

Comment: So do you know what the answer is?

Comment: Yes, I know and  there two answer to this question -15/2 and -17/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $a>-1$ and $a\neq -\frac 12$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1^a+2^a+\cdots +n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[(na+1)+(na+2)+(na+3)+\cdots+(na+n)]}
&\sim\frac {n^{a+1}/(a+1)}{n^{a-1}(a+1/2)n^2}\\
\to\frac 2{(a+1)(2a+1)}
\end{align}
from which $a=7$.
For $a<-1$ the numerator converges to  positive value, hence the limit is $-\infty $.
Finally, for $a=-\frac 12$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1^a+2^a+\cdots +n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[(na+1)+(na+2)+(na+3)+\cdots+(na+n)]}
&\sim\frac {2\sqrt n}{n^{-3/2}n/2}\\
\sim 4n\to +\infty
\end{align}
The answer $a=7$ is confirmed:
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the other solution you got? The question doesn't insist on $a>0$.

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour of the numerator doesn't hold for negative $a $.

Comment: Wrong answer the answer is already posted by me and this no doubt about the answer because it is given by very reputed institution.

Comment: The correct answer is $a=7$, see the image in my answer.

Comment: The answer to this question that is -17/2.

Comment: The method which is they have used to get the is by integration and i have not studied integration till now.

Comment: What is the source of the image, please?

Comment: See [here](https://jeeadv.ac.in/archives/past-question-papers.html), year 2013, paper 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=0}^nr^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}\sum_{r=0}^n ( na + r)}  $$

Observe that the sum can be converted to a reimann integral as,

$$S = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{(\frac{r}{n})^a}{(2a+\frac{1}{n} + 1)(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1}}$$

$$ S = 2\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{2a+1}\mathrm dx$$
$$ S = \frac{2}{(2a+1)(a+1)} = \frac{1}{60} \implies a = 7$$